# Calculate the result of the following sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck with this sequence.I can't calculate the result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$A=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{16} + \frac{4}{32} + ... $$

Please feel free to edit the tags if you wish.Thanks

Please do not edit the question I'm sure I've written it correctly.

EDIT:The nth number of this sequence is evaluated by the formula: 
$\displaystyle\frac{n}{2^{n- 2([\frac{n}{2}])+1}}$ if  i'm not mistaken.Because the denominator is multiplied by 2 at first and then by 4 and then again by 2 and ... goes on like that.

EDIT2:I've made a big mistake!The denominator itself is evaluated by :
$\displaystyle d_n=2^{n- 2([\frac{n}{2}])+1} \times d_{n-1}$ where $d_i$ is the $i$ th denominator.

EDIT3:Can anything be done using $2A-A=A$ ?I think this should get me somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm sure I've written the question correctly

Comment: @FuriousMathematician, See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence

Comment: Sorry for edit but: What is the nth member of your sequence, please?

Comment: the denominator is multiplied by 2 at first then by 4 then by 2 and ... goes on like that.I can't write the nth number

Comment: @HoseynHeydari Can you help me then?With the nth number given I mean

Answer (score 2):

It seem that you could express this series
$$C_n = \frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\frac{4}{2^5}+\frac{5}{2^7}+\frac{6}{2^8}+\dots$$
as the sum of two other series
$$C_n=A_n+B_n$$
where
$$A_n=\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{3}{2^4}+\frac{5}{2^7}+\frac{7}{2^{10}}+\dots$$
and
$$B_n=\frac{2}{2^2}+\frac{4}{2^5}+\frac{6}{2^8}+\frac{8}{2^{11}}+\dots$$

**Hint:**

$8A_n - A_n = $ ?

Comment: $A_n= \frac {8}{245}$ if I calculated correctly.Thanks!Now just a bit more help on evaluating $B_n$

Comment: Just please be quick about it I desperately need to get the answer right now :/

Comment: Can $B_n$ be evaluated the same way as $A_n$ ?

Comment: Oh darn!I calculated $A_n$ wrongly ...

Comment: @FuriousMathematician see my answer for a set of series for which you can probably find the limits quite easily

Comment: Yes. $B_n$ can be calculated the same way as $A_n$ because in both cases the numerators increase by 2 between successive terms, and the denominators increase 8 fold (e.g. $2^3$). Starting with an arithmetico-geometric series, you should end up with a simple geometric series. Thank you to Lab Bhattacharjee for helping me with my vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{d}{dx} (1+x+x^2+\dots)
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

In the same spirit as Ma Ming's answer, consider $$A=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i x^i=x\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i x^{i-1}$$ where $x=\frac 12$. As written, $A$ looks like the derivative of a function which itself is the development of a quite classical expression, isn't it ?

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: could you please give me an easier an answer?I'm kinda not familiar with these things you say since we've not been taught yet.

Comment: $A$ is $x$ times the derivative of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^i$ which is a geometric series. Is this easier ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't even know what derivative is!

Comment: Then, I am really sorry for not being able to help in simpler terms ! Be sure I apologize. Cheers :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think the result is as follows:

$A=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{16}+...$

This is equal to:

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i} - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{3i}{2^{3i}} - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^{3i+1}}+\frac{i}{2^{3i+2}}$

And you can probably evaluate this in some way.

btw, the answer is $\frac{68}{49}$